# Array size issue for converting String to Unicode

Tags: java, arrays, unicode

I have a string "text" in one class which calls on a method in another class to convert text in various ways. In this method though I am left with an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error.

```
public String toUnicode() {
    char unicodeTextArray[] = new char[text.length()];

    if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    String unicodeTextArrayString[] = new String[text.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

        unicodeTextArray[i] = text.charAt(i);

        if (unicodeTextArray[i] < 0x10) {
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u000" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
        } else if (unicodeTextArray[i] < 0x100) {
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u00" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
        } else if (unicodeTextArray[i] < 0x1000) {
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
        }
        unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
    }

    String unicode = unicodeTextArrayString[text.length()];
    return unicode;
}
```

Changing one line to an arbitrarily large number such as:

```
String unicodeTextArrayString[] = new String[9999];
```

Results in no error, but it returns null.

I thought about setting an int variable to increase the length of the array, but * 4 was still too small of an array size and it seems like if I go too large it just returns null.

How could I go about getting the correct length of the array?

EDIT: I found a non-array approach that works, but I would still like to know if there is a way to make the above array approach work in some way.

```
public String toUnicode() 
    {
        String unicodeString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) 
         { 
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            String s = String.format ("\\u%04x", (int)c);
            unicodeString = unicodeString + s;
         }
         return unicodeString;
    }
```

EDIT 2: In case anyone reading this is curious, to get the decimal value of the unicode:

```
    public String toUnicode() 
    {
        String unicodeString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) 
         { 
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            int unicodeDecimal = c;
            unicodeString = unicodeString + unicodeDecimal + " ";
         }
         return unicodeString;
    }
```

EDIT 3: I ended up deciding to use the following, which separates unicode decimals by space, and checks for the unicode value 10 (which means new line) and outputs a new line into the string instead of that value.

```
    public String toUnicode() 
    {
        String unicodeString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) 
         { 
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            int unicodeDecimal = c;  

            if (unicodeDecimal == 10)
            {
                unicodeString = unicodeString + "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                unicodeString = unicodeString + unicodeDecimal + " ";
            }

         }
         return unicodeString;
    }
```

Comment: What you want to return is the concatenated String from your unicodeTextArrayString. Use a StringBuffer/StringBuilder to buildup your string. That is much more elegant.

Comment: Misdescribed. You aren't converting a String to Unicode, you're converting it to an escaped representation of Unicode. At first. Post your edits it's impossible to tell what the objective is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things

1) Move line
`char unicodeTextArray[] = new char[text.length()];` after following code

```
    if (text == null || text.isEmpty())
    {
        return "";
    }
   char unicodeTextArray[] = new char[text.length()];
```

2) Error is because of this `String unicode = unicodeTextArrayString[text.length()];`

e.g you get a text as "hello", then you initialized unicodeTextArrayString of size text.length() which is 5. So you can fetch back from this array for index 0 to 4 only, but you are trying to fetch from index 5, which is out of bounds.

3) After having said so, the code/logic seems wrong. I just modified your logic using StringBuilder instead. You can check for conversion logic

```
public static String toUnicode(String text)
{
 if (text == null || text.isEmpty())
{
  return "";
}
StringBuilder unicodeTextArrayString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
  char ch = text.charAt(i);
  if (ch < 0x10)
  {
    unicodeTextArrayString.append("\\u000" + Integer.toHexString(ch));
  }
  else if (ch < 0x100)
  {
    unicodeTextArrayString.append("\\u00" + Integer.toHexString(ch));
  }
  else if (ch < 0x1000)
  {
    unicodeTextArrayString.append("\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(ch));
  }
  else
  {
    unicodeTextArrayString.append("\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch));
  }
}

return unicodeTextArrayString.toString();
}
```

4) If you want to use array based approach, then add each chars to arrays, and then iterate again through array where u stored chars, and then build a string (instead of getting a string from last index) and then return the string

Comment: You can simplify the loop by replacing all the `if` statements with a single `String.format()` call instead: `for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { unicodeTextArrayString.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) text.charAt(i))); }`

Answer (score 0):

this one is the culprit

```
String unicode = unicodeTextArrayString[text.length()];
```

edit:
If you really want to make the original code to work in some way, I think there are several ways to do it. The following code is one of them.

```
public String toUnicode() {
    char unicodeTextArray[] = new char[text.length()];

    if (text == null) {
        return "";
    }

    String unicodeTextArrayString[] = new String[text.length()];

    StringBuilder unicode= new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

        unicodeTextArray[i] = text.charAt(i);

        if (unicodeTextArray[i] < 0x10) {
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u000" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
        } else if (unicodeTextArray[i] < 0x100) {
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u00" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
        } else if (unicodeTextArray[i] < 0x1000) {
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);
        } else 
            unicodeTextArrayString[i] = "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(unicodeTextArray[i]);

        unicode = unicode.append(unicodeTextArrayString[i]);
    }

    return unicode.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that this is the problem. As I wrote above, when I change that to an arbitrarily large number it compiles without error. The problem is that I don't know what the array length should be for that line.

Comment: @Elliander his point is that youre indexing the array (out of bounds) when it appears that you want to take all the elements together as a single string, which isnt what that line does

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. This line specifically creates the array and sets the length of the array. That's why I specifically said that in the question.